# Unable to convert latex to pdf - Overleaf

Tags: pdf, viewers

I am using Overleaf to create my resume with LaTeX. When I compile the code, the preview is totally fine, and so is the pdf obtained from it when viewed on a laptop or IOS phone. However, when it is viewed on an Android phone, the words get all jumbled up and no longer make any sense. I have tried changing the encoding to utf-8, latin1 etc. but nothing works.

I am attaching the screenshot of the problematic pdf.
Thank You[image: The incorrect pdf]

Comment: Hi KaranMalik and welcome to TeX.SE! This seems to be an issue of your Android PDF viewer. Can you please specify which reader you are using? Have you tried Adobe Reader for Android?

Comment: which fonts are you using in your document? Can you show a small but complete document that can be used for tests?